# Books Recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, reference-request

I am studying mathematics and would like to improve and learn in many areas. It is still very difficult for me to understand topics such as topology and analysis (sequences for example) without having a visual image and I am looking for books in which mathematical proofs are reinforced with an illustration and presented more simply.

I would be very happy about recommendations from you.

Comment: What are some books on analysis or topology that you’ve tried to read?

Comment: Maybe have a look [there](https://www.thefreeflightsite.com/best-mathematical-analysis-books/#product-6)

Comment: I've tried to read a book from Rudin in Analysis and I always try to look in several books for more details and explanations of proofs to understand them better if I did not understand them in the lecture notes. I've got my Bachelor degree in maths and would like to improve much more now to get further in mathematics.

Comment: This question has probably been asked and answered on this website already. Please do a search for previous occurrences. Maybe search for questions with the reference-request tag.

Comment: @vitalmath the books of Rudin are terrible to learn mathematics. For an introduction to real analysis the IMHO best book I know is *Understanding Analysis* of Stephen Abbott

Comment: @vitalmath You can also have a look at following text"Visual Complex Analysis" by T. Needham suggested by user: Jean Marie in comments under my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Analysis: You can have a look on Understanding Analysis by Stephan Abott, Mathematical Analysis By Tom M Apostol.

Abott has really good examples along with good and intuitive explanation of theorems and solutions of exercises are also given. He begins each chapter with  motivation to results given in the chapter .

Apostol explains theorems in very nice way and exercises are great for practice. Multivariable calculus is also there and it also covers uniform convergence, lebesgue integration, fourier series which is not in Abott's book. But  abbot's
text is great to start real analysis and understand the motivation and intuition behind it.

For Topology: Foundations of Topology By Wayne Patty.

This book has very good explanation of concepts of general  topology  with good number of solved examples in every chapter.

For Complex Analysis: Complex Analysis by Rolf Busam, Eberhard Freitag.

Hope it helps!

Comment: For complex analysis, "Visual Complex Analysis" by T. Needham meets the desire of abundant graphical representations of @vitalmath

Comment: @JeanMarie Ya, It has a lot of graphs!

Comment: Thank you so so much! I'll have a look at all of this!